# insert performance degraded after dropping and re creating columnstore index on a partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database, database-partitioning, columnstore

The table was partitioned but the range was set to 20, lately the range was exhausted so we increased the range from 20 to 5000. The table had clustered column store index on it so we had to follow these below steps

1. Drop Clustered column store index on the table
2. Extended the range by following statement, this was done in loop till 4999 range
   ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partitionfunctionname() SPLIT RANGE (21);
   ALTER PARTITION SCHEME partitionschemaname NEXT USED [PRIMARY]
3. Created the Clustered column store index back on the table

Now we see the insertion is taking more time the same operation which would be completed within 10 mins is taking 60 mins. I read about fragmentation does this has to do anything with it

Note: Table is on azure sql database

Comment: Please add relevant table and index definitions, and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: You don't need to put each value into its own partition.  Having 5000 partitions will likely be slower than having fewer.  Please explain why you are partitioning at all - Columnstores generally have their own internal logic to split into chunks and you don't need to do partitioning on top of that to try to improve performance - it won't.

Comment: We are not storing data in 5000 partition, the complete database is snapshot and stored in one partition, we do monthly snapshot and also have provision for custom snapshot that user can request. So these snapshot will be stored in table partition wise and user will have flexibility to compare data between snapshot for his data analysis. Currently we have 20 snapshots which has filled the existing partition range so we extended it to a bigger number so that we don't need to increase it often. And also not all snapshots will be active only the latest snapshot will be reloaded on daily basis.